# Making Android NDK apps with NativeActivity?

Tags: windows, eclipse, android-ndk, mingw

I know that in a normal NDK build, the C++ libraries are built and packed into an apk file. But how can I automate this in Eclipse? I have tried following http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/ to run the native-activity sample that came with the NDK, and it ended up not working. Even after I got past most of the reference errors via including, nothing happens when I run it as an Android Application (with a Motorola phone plugged in).

I have looked around quite a bit about this and am still stuck, so I'm open to suggestions at this point. Thanks!

(Please keep in mind that I'm using MinGW/MSys on Windows 7, mostly for running scripts with bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just decided to go with an Ubuntu VM and use that, and with some tweaking it seems to be working the way it should. I used a combination of http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/ and http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html#native-activity to get everything set up. Also a very important note, go to C/C++ General -> Code Analysis -> Launching in your Eclipse project settings and disable both of those options for any native activities you make. I'm not sure if there's a good way to set the libs and includes up for it to work, but currently live bug checking screws things up in the NDK, and I can currently build successfully without it. Plus it'll still mark errors in red after a failed build, so you shouldn't be completely in the middle of nowhere when finding errors.

Comment: my upvote. Your post was really helpful since I am going through the same problems.