# running the NDK native-activity sample from a command-line IDE

Tags: android, android-ndk

similar questions have been asked:

[How to run NDK samples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779368/how-to-run-ndk-samples)

[Making Android NDK apps with NativeActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681822/making-android-ndk-apps-with-nativeactivity)

I've got the [command-line](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html) documentation down to the point where I can create an empty Android project, I do not know how to build-install-run the NDK examples, particularly the [NativeActivity one](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html), in a non-Eclipse build environment (Ubuntu 10.0.04).

So my questions are

1. does the NativeActivity example "just work" or do you have to do something besides just `$adb -d shell "am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.nativeActivity"`?
2. How do you build, install, run the [NativeActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html) example?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-ndk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't answer about this specific example. But here's the general process for building and installing an Android application which uses the NDK.

1. `cd` to the root of its source code.
2. Run `ndk-build`. This builds the native code, and should result in some `.so` files being put into the `libs` directory.
3. `android update project --path . --name something`
4. `ant debug` (or similar). This will build the Java code and create an .apk. Crucially, the build process will pick up the `.so` files left within the `libs` directory and include them into the .apk.
5. `adb install bin/name-of-project.apk`
6. Then launch as normal using the Android GUI or using an `am start` command such as you give.

Comment: This works perfectly fine with NativeActivty, I am using `am start` command for NativeActivity all the time.

Comment: on building the nativeactivity example, I'm getting a make build fail: fatal error: jni.h: no such file.

Comment: Sorry to hear that - not sure what's up, but Googling for that problem shows various possible solutions even here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AdrianTaylor I got this one myself (no Google!) it was an `include` issue. check out my other question to see hwo I solved it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866739/include-jni-h-and-compile-with-arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Comment: Don't forget to add an API target to the tail of your command:

android update project --path . --name projectname --target 20